# In windows 10 is there a way to have different color or font for read only files

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, file-attributes

I'm trying to know if windows 10 File Explorer allows showing a different color or different font in the file name or icon depending on the attributes of that file.

Example:

- Attribute "Archive" file name in blue
- Attribute "Read Only" file name in red

Comment: Blue is reserved for NTFS-compressed files

Comment: I'm looking to find a way to view it in the file explorer! I said blue as an example, it can be any other color, i just want to be able to visually differentiate the files attributes in the explorer!

Comment: I found a [TechRadar article](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-color-code-files-and-folders-in-windows-10) which shows 2 different free tools to colorize folders and icons. As you specify file attributes, seems you'd like to have this happen automatically. I didn't go deeper to check whether either of these apps have that kind of auto coloring capability. I updated your question based on the comment above - please check it and correct in case I misunderstood your meaning.